# Add listener to a svg element which is imported in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, event-listener

I need to add event listeners on a canvas elements (I know they are not actually elements). I've understood that this is possible only with svg. So I imported some svg elements into the canvas following the example given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas). 
And this is what my code looks like:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//wherever I put the id inside the svg element it does not fire the event
var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
       '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
       '<div id="asdf" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
         '<em >I</em> like ' + 
         '<span style="color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;">' +
         'cheese</span>' +
       '</div>' +
       '</foreignObject>' +
       '</svg>';
var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
img.src = url;
document.getElementById('asdf').addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert('AJDEEE');
});
```

If I attach the listener to the canvas it works. But when it is attached to an element inside the svg it does not.
So am I wrong anywhere or it is just impossible that way ?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Should the `addEventListener` be inside the `img.onload` function..?

Comment: Yes I tried it. No difference.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: see `document.getElementById('asdf')` is null that is why nothing happens

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y0qfpufu/ .

Answer (score 0):

You take the SVG, you render it to canvas so now you've got a raster. That's all you have to click on, the raster. The SVG is gone.